# Missing Ethernet Interface in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04

I'm having an issue with my Ubuntu 20.04 install where I have no ethernet interface and I can't find a way to get it back. My situation is very similar to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310443/only-lo-interface-in-etc-netplan-ubuntu-20-04) question but I'm unable to get access to an external NIC and I'm doubtful that would even work for me. I have a USB wifi dongle but it isn't recognized by the system and I've been unable to build the drivers (when I try to compile them I get a compilation error). When I did this install I chose the minimal install option which may be why the USB adapter isn't recognized.

Any help getting at least the ethernet connection working again would be really appreciated. I've spent a bunch of time customizing this install and I'd rather not have to go through and re-do all that work if I can avoid it. At the end of the day I can always re-install but I'd like to avoid it.

**Background**

This started with an issue with my screen resolution being stuck at 800x600 due to some driver issues. I've fixed this issue before but had forgotten exactly how so I did some Googling and followed a few solutions none of which worked for me. I had other things to deal with so I gave up on the issue and left the PC for a few weeks. When I got back around to this issue I also noticed that I no longer had a network connection. After trying a few things (none of which I can remember now), replacing the network cable, getting a new motherboard, CPU, and RAM (I wanted an upgrade anyways and thought maybe the ancient board I was using was finally dying) I realized something else was wrong.

I can't install anything directly on the machine, I've been able to install a few packages by downloading them and their dependencies on another machine, putting them on a USB, and installing them off the USB. Below is the output from a bunch of commands that I've seen in other threads.

**`ip a`**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

**`sudo lshw -C network`**

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:25:00.0
       version: 15
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:f000(size=256) memory:f7504000-f7504fff memory:f7500000-f7503fff
```

**`lspci`**

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-1fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 59)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 7
03:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43bc (rev 02)
03:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43b8 (rev 02)
03:00.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43b3 (rev 02)
20:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 02)
20:05.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 02)
20:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 02)
20:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] 300 Series Chipset PCIe Port (rev 02)
25:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
29:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP107 [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti] (rev a1)
29:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP107GL High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)
2a:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Zeppelin/Raven/Raven2 PCIe Dummy Function
2a:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Platform Security Processor
2a:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Zeppelin USB 3.0 Host controller
2b:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Zeppelin/Renoir PCIe Dummy Function
2b:00.2 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)
2b:00.3 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller
```

**`cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml`**

```
#Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

**`modinfo r8168`/`modinfo r8169`**

Both of these commands generate a module not found message

**Edit**

After writing my question I tried installing the `dkms` and `r8168-dkms` and that worked fine but I still didn't have a network connection. I'm fairly certain I tried `sudo modprobe r8169` at this point but I may not have. I also tried install `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` as mentioned in another question and that didn't finish due to some errors.

After seeing @Terrance's comment I decided to try `sudo modprobe r8169` again and that worked. Either I didn't actually run the command previously or my attempt to install `linux-generic-hwe-20.04` worked just enough to get the driver working (I'm not sure if that's even possible).

The end result is that my system is working enough I should be able to fix it but I don't know the exact fix which irks me more

Comment: Just to confirm: you installed Ubuntu with the previous motherboard, switched over to a new one with a new CPU, and plugged the storage device in without a reinstallation. Correct? 

Comment: So `sudo modprobe r8169` is failing as well?  Once the r8169 driver is working I would recommend installing the r8168 driver that works with dkms https://askubuntu.com/questions/1305616/unable-to-make-ethernet-work/1305665#1305665

Comment: May we also see: `sudo dpkg -s linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r) | grep Status`

Comment: In my comment above there is a link on installing the r8168 driver for your device.  The r8169 is stable but only on a 8169 chipset.  Yours uses the 8168.